# In laravel when i try to change my from a livewire component to a regular laravel component i get a syntax error, unexpected token "<" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-livewire

Im at a loss at what can be causing this issue, I know it has to do with me using the Laravel component syntax because when i change my component from a Livewire component which was working fine but I just wasn't using it for anything that needs Livewire for, to a Laravel component it throws me the error:
syntax error, unexpected token "<" (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/components/product-actions.blade.php)

The error goes away when i comment out the component so its definitely coming from there. The new component is an exact copy of the Livewire component with no changes and even when i comment out every line inside the new component so its completely void of any code it'll still show me the error which proves to me that it isn't caused by the code inside the component but by the way I'm calling the component. The component is the "<x-products.product-edit-modal />"

```
@if (sizeof(getSelectedLocations()) > 1 && $edit )
    <button class="border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-lg px-3 py-1"
        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ __('datatable.cannot_edit') }}">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i><br>
    </button>

@elseif(!(sizeof(getSelectedLocations()) > 1) && $edit)

    @livewire('product-edit-modal',
        [
            'model' => $model,
        ],
        key('product-edit-modal-'.$model->id)
    )

    <x-products.product-edit-modal
        :model="{{ $model }}"
        :currentSupplierId="{{ $model->custom_props_location_supplier->first()->supplier->id ?? null }}"
        :categories="{{ $categories }}" />

    {{-- @livewire('product-edit-modal-main',
        [
            'model' => $model,
            'current_supplier_id' => $model->custom_props_location_supplier->first()->supplier->id ?? null,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ],
        key('product-edit-modal-main-'.$model->id)) --}}

@elseif(sizeof(getSelectedLocations()) > 1 && !$edit)

    <button class="border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-lg px-3 py-1"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ __('datatable.cannot_edit') }}">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><br>
    </button>

@else
    <x-orders.add-product-to-order-modal-button :product="$model" />
    <span></span>
    <x-orders.add-product-to-order-modal currentSupplierId="{{ $current_supplier_id }}" :product="$model" />
@endif
```

Code inside the component commented out

```
{{-- <div class="modal fade" id="product-edit-modal-{{ $model->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryModalTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="form">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center pt-2 mt-2 me-3">
                <div class="w-8"></div>
                    <h2 class="text-center text-xl font-bold">{{ $custom_props_product_location->custom_name ?? str_replace(['~~ '], '', $model->category->name) }}</h2>
                <div class="w-8">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" dir="{{ app()->getLocale() === 'he' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' }}">
                @livewire('product-edit-form',
                    [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'current_supplier_id' => $current_supplier_id,
                        'custom_props_product_supplier_location' => $custom_props_product_supplier_location,
                        'custom_props_product_location' => $custom_props_product_location,
                        'categories' => $categories,
                    ],
                    key('product-edit-form-'.$model->id)
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> --}}
```

I believe it may have something to do with how im using mix also so ill provide that here.
Inside webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

In the head of the app

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'HaShuk') }}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1845edc72d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

    @stack('styles')

    @livewireStyles

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
```

Comment: do you know the line number? in error trace, it will display the line number as well. and BTW You will need to check the cached view file to go to that line number.

Comment: The error trace has problems when it comes to errors inside of a blade file, however Ive tracked down the error to when i call the component  <x-products.product-edit-modal />, if i comment out that line the error doesn't show up